# CSS/JS don't load after changing URL

Tags: magento2, configuration, url, base-url, js-css

[image]

I have two store views, I changed one of them from **wesbitetest.com** to **websitetest.com/fr-ca/** but the front end didn't load the js and CSS files as expected, and the URL becomes websitetest.com/fr-ca/?___store=fr_ca instead of **websitetest.com/fr-ca/**

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Run commands:php bin/magento setup:di:compile,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy,
php bin/magento cache:clean,
php bin/magento cache:flush,

& After give permission var & pub folder

Comment: @bramulous yes please see the screenshot I added to the original post

Comment: Clean the content of `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` then launch this command : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_CA -f` if you are using `fr_CA` language otherwise replace it with your local language code`

Comment: the thing is if i do **Stores->Configuration>"Add store code to URLS"->yes**
it will add the store code which is fr_ca and not fr-ca, it only accepts the underscore :s

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands on your server to make sure that everything is deployed well after that change.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:static-content:deploy -j 10 -f en_US fr_CA
mage setup:di:compile
mage maintenance:disable
```

Comment: could you please explain to me this mage setup:static-content:deploy -j 10 -f en_US fr_CA 

in my case i have fr-ca and en-a

and another website that has one store view en-us ..

Comment: This command will deploy the static files for both languages, it won't set any configuration, you can run this commands even if you haven't used en_US ou fr_CA.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to help you efficiently, such as what have you already tried, any errors, any permissions issues, etc.

In the meantime, you can follow standard theme debugging steps:

Make sure your theme settings are scoped correctly, under

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

In addition, you will want to clear our your pub/static/frontend/* and var/view_preprocessed/* directories.
`rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed/*`

You should then try as Abdul suggested: compile, deploy static content, and clear caches.

Comment: it broke the whole front end in all stores when i cleaned and deployed, 
with these errors: 
efused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
require.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://dev4.wetag.ca/pub/static/version1522434789/frontend/Magento/luma/en_CA/requirejs/require.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/htm